# Метод для чтения значения с клавиатуры java

Tags: java, методы

Есть следующий код:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите число в пределах от 10 до 99: ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
if (n < 10 || n > 99) {
    System.out.println("Число не попадает в заданный диапазон");
    return;
}
```

Требуется заменить часть кода, написав свой метод `readInt(msg, from, to)`.

Подскажите, какую часть данного кода может заменить подобный метод? Непонятно, какое сообщение передать в качестве аргумента и что в итоге будет делать этот метод (только чтение переменной? проверку на попадание в диапазон?)

Comment: Сообщение это имеется ввиду ввод с клавиатуры. И да - метод должен делать проверку на попадание в диапазон.

Comment: Метод ReadInt должен возвращать значение типа boolean

Comment: @НиколайБеляков это ваш вопрос?